# What does persisting in Spark 2.0 refer to?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Assume I'm working in pyspark. I have a RDD, `rdd = sc.Textfile(file.txt)`, and I call `rdd.persist()`
and then reassign it as such: `rdd = rdd.filter(lambda x: 'hi' in x)`.

Now is `sc.Textfile(file.txt)` being persisted in memory or is `rdd.filter(lambda x: 'hi' in x)` now being persisted?

Comment: The rdd that you have read from file.txt text file is persisted and filter is applied on the persisted data. persist ensures that reading from text file will not occur even if you apply action on the rdd created.

Comment: Rdd are immutable

Answer (score 0):

In spark the RDDs are evaluated on-demand.
for example:

```
rdd1 = rdd.map(r=>e)     
rdd1.count()
```

The count() action will trigger evaluation of mapping transformation on rdd after reading records from hdfs.

If you execute  `rdd1.count()` again (or any action on rdd)  then all previous transformations in rdd chain will be executed again.

However, in order to avoid the RDD re-evaluations we can persist the computed RDDs.
`rdd1.persist()` will save the transformed RDD in-memory and will not trigger re-evaluation of rdd1 when additional actions are performed on rdd1.

There are several persistence mode like in-memory, disk only or combination of these. Check the persistence modes [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence).